# SSO authentication with SAML2 in Java and How to Execute JavaScript by Using HtmlUnit

Tags: java, authentication, single-sign-on, kerberos, htmlunit

In one of my developments (using kerberos authentication to loginalong with HtmlUnit) its working fine in all cases , facing an issue after hitting SSO authenticated links where the SAML2 used.

I have searched all the way there is no proper explanation to get more info on SAML2 authentication for SSO secured pages.

I`m completely new for SSO authentication and SAML2 authentication,is there any separate API for this? help me to know on more on this.

Could you please help or suggest what is the best process to pass the user/password to get the authentication.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Authentication itself is not part of SAMLv2 specification. SAMLv2 defines the exchange of information about authenticated subjects. Authentication happens at the SAMLv2 IdP. How this happens in detail is up to the IdP.
It could be that the following is possible in your case ...
Use HTTP POST to send credentials to the Login URL of the IdP. Capture the session cookie returned by the IdP. Send HTTP request to the endpoint of the IdP which allows so called IdP-initiated SSO and specify 'HTTP Redirect Binding' and the Meta Alias of the SP (this is the SSO-enabled app from SAML point of view). The IdP would return a 302 , follow the redirect, the SP should consume the SAML assertion included as a query parameter and you should be able to access the SSO-enabled app.

You may read SAMLv2 tech overview (http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.html) to get some idea.

Comment: thanks for your update on this, Already we are doing the authentication for this,even though I got your point:we have to post the same credentials to the the  IdP URL. 
As of now we are doing all this by using the HtmlUnit
Ex:I`m trying hitting an URL,after authentication with this code (HtmlPage page = webCilent.getPage("https://www.aby.com/xyz") then this would redirects to IdP URL, I`m getting the same page while printing it,as its now allowing to move forwards due to the IdP 

Could you please share some sample code with above scenario -

Comment: After authentication started printing 'page.asXML'  then we came to know that the response coming with '<noscript>' tag and in complete page we could see only one function with Request to post.

We are hitting 'https:/xyz.com' URL with WebClient, which has SSO authentication due to this its redirecting to idp.
When we print the page its showing idp redirection Page instead of the actual page.

After this as we have thinking to execute the script with **HtmlUnit** , but its not allowing to get the proper page. Could you please help to execute the **Javascript** in HtmlUnit